# Angular 8 getting error like Property 'ASSIGNMENT' does not exist on type '[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I have been working on Angular 8 and my typescript code is as below.

```
public agencyName: any;
this.agencyName = data.data.data.ASSIGNMENT.AGENT.COMPANY_CUSTOMER.COMPANY_NAME.split("|")[0].trim();
```

here COMPANY_NAME name is like "company_short_name | company_full_name".
When I have checked with localhost:4200 port it working properly and I am able to get value after splitting with pipe.

But after build I am getting error saying.

```
ERROR in src/app/property-detail/component.ts(63,57): error TS2339: Property 'ASSIGNMENT' does not exist on type '[]'.
```

I have tried lot to find solution online but not have any luck.
Please let me know if anyone have idea about it .

data.data.data.ASSIGNMENT value is like below.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error message indicates that `data.data.data.ASSIGNMENT` is an array. Have you tried to inspect this?

Comment: yes. data.data.data.ASSIGNMENT is dict object.I have added value of it in question.

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` and please post the result.

Comment: I think there are more issues, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data.data.data.ASSIGNMENT` is a dictionary, and key `AGENT` exists inside dictionary, you'll need to index it.

Error message indicates that `data.data.data` is a collection, so you will need to index that as well, e.g.:

```
this.agencyName = data.data.data[0].ASSIGNMENT['AGENT'].COMPANY_CUSTOMER.COMPANY_NAME.split("|")[0].trim();
```

Comment: getting error saying ASSIGNMENT does not have get function.

Comment: @Moon: My bad, wrong Angular version, please try data.data.data.ASSIGNMENT['AGENT']

Comment: Thanks Roar. It's working but I have set it like data.data.data['ASSIGNMENT']['AGENT']['COMPANY_CUSTOMER']['COMPANY_NAME'].split("|")[0].trim();  It will be great help if you will explain it more why it is working.

Comment: @Moon: Nice, good to hear that things are working now. So `data.data.data` was a dictionary.

Comment: S , Can you please explain what is the issue ? Why earlier not working ?

Comment: @Moon: When you're working with dictionaries, you'll need to specify a key in dictionary for code to use, else code will have no clue what to do. Same applies to arrays.